# Import files from s3 bucket into hadoop program (in java, eclipse)

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, emr

I'm trying to add cache files to my job.
I have split files in s3 bucket directory. "s3n:pathSomthing " 
and I want to import them in the setup in the Mapper class.

I tried this code in the main :

```
 job.addCacheFile(new URI(args[1])); //path of the s3 with the files
```

and in the Mapper, in Setup I used:

```
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        System.out.println("entring setup");
        URI [] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
        if((cacheFiles != null) && (cacheFiles.length >0)) {
            for (URI cacheFile : cacheFiles) {
                Path path = new Path(cacheFile.getPath().toString());
                   if (fs.exists(path)) {
                FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(path);
                readFile(in);
                in.close();
                   }
            }
        }
```

What is the right way to open and read the whole files?

Thank you!

Comment: `readFile` is not working? Doesn't that return something??